# How to make a Vector2 offset point always be relative to transform's rotation in topdown shooter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm setting up shooting in my game, but the projectile start point (end of weapon) doesn't rotate with player. The point is defined by a Vector2 on the script which is supposed to be an offset from the player position, but also accounting for player rotation too.
I'm sure its something really simple, but can't seem to work out how to fix my code. (I want to do it using code in this script, rather than a child transform reference)

In the pics, the start point is shown as a green circle with red cross through it. It needs to rotate with player, so its always at the tip of the arrow.

```
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    localProjectileStart = new Vector3(
        transform.position.x + projectileStart.x,
        transform.position.y + projectileStart.y,
        transform.position.z);
    Gizmos.color = Color.green;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(localProjectileStart, 0.04f);
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector3(-0.05f, 0, 0) + localProjectileStart, new Vector3(0.05f, 0, 0) + localProjectileStart);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector3(0, -0.05f, 0) + localProjectileStart, new Vector3(0, 0.08f, 0) + localProjectileStart);
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while to figure out, but I got it working as a fully code-based position-offset solution:

```
public Vector2 projectileStart;
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    // Script-based constant position offset
    Vector3 _localPositionAndRotation = transform.rotation * new Vector3(
        projectileStart.x,
        projectileStart.y,
        0);
    Vector3 _relativePosition = _localPositionAndRotation + transform.position;
    Gizmos.color = Color.green;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(_relativePosition, 0.04f);
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawLine((transform.right * -0.05f) + _relativePosition, (transform.right * 0.05f) + _relativePosition);
    Gizmos.DrawLine((transform.up * -0.05f) + _relativePosition, (transform.up * 0.08f) + _relativePosition);
}
```

This code draws a wire sphere (doesn't rotate) at the offset point, and also a T-like arrow-of-sorts which always points to transform.up, so that its very easy to get the 2D-forward direction. In my case, I use this for  player and enemy projectile weapons.
Using OnDrawGizmos gives an editor-only view of the placement, then in my Update code, I do the exact same thing for use when the game is running.

Thankyou to @SushiWaUmai for the tips on multiplying by transform.rotation.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a new GameObject and make it a child of the player object so that the point rotates with the player. You can get a reference to the point and get its position.

Comment: Thanks. I do know this way, but was aiming to do it by code rather than be dependant on another GameObject reference. I think I've done it before, maybe using things like transform.up/etc, but I can't get it working now and haven't found answers online. Any ideas?

Comment: You could calculate the relative Vector and multiply it with the player's rotation to rotate the Vector.

Comment: Ok, how would I write that in C# code, to change the ```localProjectileStart``` variable? I've tried a number of different ways to multiply but none correct yet. (Player rotates on Z axis, btw)
The code is where I'm having trouble

Comment: How do you rotate the Vector?

Comment: I tried rotating each individual axis of localProjectileStart by transform.rotation.z (and other rotation axis), and also multiplying the whole Vector by transform.rotation.z. All effects were wrong, mainly in not staying around the player (flying off) when turning.
I don't think I understand how to multiply it by rotation in the way you suggest

Comment: You can rotate a Vector3 by multiplying it by a Quaternion, more info under https://forum.unity.com/threads/rotate-vector-by-quaternion.21687/

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't know that the order mattered. Thats probably what caused some of my issues. I'll see if I can fix now.